# Typescript import with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript1.4

I'm trying to create a simple node app to test out typescript, and I'm having trouble with the type definitions and import. Here is my code:

```
/// <reference path="./node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./underscore.d.ts" />

import _ = require('underscore');
```

I'm getting an error `File node.d.ts` not found. This stops TS from building. The d.ts files are in the same directory, but won't resolve. Can someone point me in the right direction?